# Magento 2 How can i create a custom factory class for a class?

Tags: magento2, custom, factory

I want to initialize some data on `factory->create()` without passing in the `create(["mydata" => 1])`.

What's the way to create `MyFactoryClass` with custom `create()` for `MyClass` in my module?

I find not dev doc for the same or any article.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let's say that your class for which you want the factory is this `Vendor\Module\Model\MyClass`.
now you can create the class `Vendor\Module\Model\MyClassFactory` in the same folder as your initial class.

```
namespace Vendor\Module\Model;

class MyClassFactory implements MyInterface
{
 .....
     public function create() 
     {
     ......
     }
}

class MyInterfaceFactory extends MyClassFactory
{
    // this class is added so that there no Type Error
    // while using MyInterfaceFactory/MyClassFactory
}
```

Creating this means that Magento will not autogenerate the factory class for your class anymore. It will use your factory instead.

Comment: What are the benefits of factory class ?

Comment: @HamendraSunthwal. You have one single point of instantiating the same kind objects, you can mock it easily in unit tests

Comment: @Marius Thanks for the confirmation!
 `MyClass` is implemented by `MyInterface` so `MyInterfaceFactory` needs to be mapped in `di.xml` to  my custom `MyClassFactory` ?

Comment: Also getting this error for no reason: `Magento/Framework/Exception/RuntimeException with message 'Type Error occurred when creating object: `

Comment: clear the contents of generated/code and generated/metadata

Comment: Yes done everything still Type error, because:
`MyInterfaceFactory` generated class is not the same as `MyClassFactory` causing Type Error in construct.

What to do for cases where we inject Interface Factories like `MyInterfaceFactory` ?